# Getting bad request accessing get api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

My api method is like

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("searchText")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMeData([FromUri] string searchText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText.Trim()))
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var response = myrepo.GetData(searchText);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
}
```

I am trying to call api from postman like

```
http://localhost/api/myData?searchText=ex
```

But i am getting 404 error. What is wrong with that request.

I even tried

`http://localhost/api/myData/searchText/ex`

Comment: You need to change FromUri attribute to FromQuery if you wish searchText to be a query parameter. Also, have you enabled swaggger support in your project - this will show you the semantics of your endpoint

Comment: @auburg why change to FromQuery?

Comment: Well, is it meant to be a query parameter was my question ?

Comment: @auburg can you tell me how to use FromUri parameter in postman?

Comment: Try changing your route to something else i.e Search so then you'd have http://localhost/api/<controller name>/Search/<your search text>

Comment: As i said enabling swagger would allow your to test your endpoints without having to use Postman initially

Comment: @James What is `myData`? does it a controller name? and you are using route `/searchtext` and then query also `searchtext` which will make the route something like `http://localhost/api/myData/searchText?searchText=ex`